# Permanently setting PATH from CMD windows 8

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm setting up a custom command line utility, and the 'installer' adds a PATH entry. It works after this **for the current session**. After I close and open the command prompt, the PATH is reset and the command line isn't available any more. What's this about and how do I permanently set it from CMD?

Comment: This is a duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358265/how-to-update-path-variable-permanently-from-cmd-windows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### How do I permanently set the `PATH` from a `cmd` shell?

You need to use `setx` instead of `set`.

Example:

```
SetX PATH "c:\my dir;%PATH%"
```

Notes:

- `"`s are recommended in case any of the path elements contain spaces.
- The `cmd` shell should be run as Administrator.
- Use `/m` to set the `PATH` in the system environment instead of the user environment.

Warning:

- See my answer [Why does Windows have a limit on environment variables at all?](https://superuser.com/a/1070354/337631) for a discussion on how long the `PATH` is allowed to be without errors.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [setx](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) - Set environment variables permanently, SETX can be used to set Environment Variables for the machine (HKLM) or currently logged on user (HKCU).