# Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL in envoirement variable

Tags: windows-7, path, environment-variables

Here is my path variable

```
C:\Users\hzhao\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2\bin;
C:\Users\hzhao\.dnx\bin;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;
c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;
C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Data Protection\TSS\bin\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX;
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox
```

I want to remove some of them because I want to add new ones. The maximum of the entire string is limited to 2048 I heard. So can I delete some of related the machine such as `Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL`?

Comment: What else are you wanting to add to your PATH, and why?

Comment: I had a situation. The last string was trimmed because of length. I have to install many programs in my machine.

Comment: Also note that *On computers running Microsoft Windows 7 and later, the maximum PATH environment variable size that you can use is 4095 characters (but the system restart is required).* [Source](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/limitation-to-the-length-of-the-system-path-variable)

Comment: @DrZoo, I don't know. Actually in my Windows 7, I had a situation the PATH environment variable was truncated to 2048 automatically.

Comment: 2048 is a realistic limit. See my answer [Why does Windows have a limit on environment variables at all?](http://superuser.com/a/1070354) for the reasons why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the other values, but as the question is asking specifically about the `Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL` values, I'll refer to them.

`Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL` is used by the Intel DAL client service. This service manages the host side when using Intel DAL (Dynamic Loader Application). It's listed in Windows Services as `Intel(R) Dynamic Application Loader Host Interface Service` or in short `jhi_service` (BTW- If you don't know about this Intel feature, try google it...).

Intel DAL is used by security-based applications such as [Intel IPT](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/identity-protection/identity-protection-technology-general.html), [Intel SGX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Guard_Extensions), China UnionPay PoS, and more.

If you sure that you don't use this service, then you can delete `Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL` and `Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT` from your path.

BTW- You always can try to remove it, and if you see related errors (like dll finding errors)- paste it back.

Comment: I can remove it. But if fails, can I get it from somewhere? I assume that it is a dll.

Comment: @Love Removing something from your path does not remove any files from you computer. You can always add it back to the path later.

Answer (score 1):

I tried posting a reply to Intel's official message board on this topic (link below) but it has been closed for discusssion.

--Intel folders in the PATH variable |Intel Communities:
https://communities.intel.com/thread/46711

I deleted all of these in my path and I'm still typing, so that is good.

Apparently there is some fishyness about these hardware level processes running below the OS (see link below). Perhaps there are security benefits with the application mentioned by user3114639. Care to chime in if you know if they affect the average general user?

--Secret of Intel Management Engine by Igor Skochinsky - SlideShare:
https://www.slideshare.net/codeblue_jp/igor-skochinsky-enpub