# How to remove length restriction of system path in user command prompt?

Tags: windows-10, path

I must have misunderstood, but I thought that as long as I don't have user's PATH, content of PATH should be same between user command prompt and admin command prompt. But I turned out to be wrong.

I have a long system path (4948 characters) - the size was a result after I removed duplicates and unnecessary paths. When I opened the two different command prompts and typed "PATH", the results were different. PATH in admin command prompt show correct content but PATH in user command prompt was cut off, only showing 4096 characters.

Is there any way to remove the restriction in user command prompt?

Comment: See my answer https://superuser.com/a/1070354/337631

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for your comment. But your answer doesn't seem to exactly apply here. I didn't have (or didn't notice) this string-length problem in Windows 7. I just want same path as in admin command prompt.