# Windows path variable contains wrong entry

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables, path

I know that the resulting path is the concatenation of system + user variables. However, my resulting path contains an entry which I don't know where is coming from, and on top of that is malformed, so it's causing some problems.

> C:\Users\sarc83518>path
> PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;C:\Program Files\gradle\gradle-6.8\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;c:\dev;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7;C:\Users\L1_asarco\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\sarc83518.jdks\jdk-16.0.1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;**C:\Users\sarc83518.jdks\jdk-16.0.1=:\Users\sarc83518.jdks\openjdk-8u282-b0;**%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

(look at the entry in bold)

These are my system variables:
[image: These are my system variables]

And this is my user variable:
[image]

As you can see, this wrong entry appears between my system and user variables, and I have no idea where is it coming from.
How can I get rid of it?

Edit: here's the value of JAVA_HOME, and Java works fine, that's not the problem.
[image]
I'm not adding anything to the path manually, the entry in bold just appears there and I don't know where is coming from, it causes problems with some application that tries to read the path entries one by one and fails at that one because is not a valid path.

I'm going to delete duplicate entries, but that is not causing this issue.

Edit2: Volatile Environment, looks good.
[image]

Comment: I would almost guarantee you have extended the length [1920](https://superuser.com/questions/1070272/why-does-windows-have-a-limit-on-environment-variables-at-all) that is allowed for a system variable.  The simplest solution most likely would be to set the value of the PATH variable, within a command prompt, to a different value.  You could use the GUI to copy the entire string, set the variable to something short, then set it back to the original text value.  I am guessing you have ran something like `java -version` only for it to fail?

Comment: Did you not forget a semicolon when appending to `PATH`? `C:\Users\sarc83518>path` vs. `C:\Users\sarc83518;>path`?

Comment: @Ramhound: His PATH is only 1016 characters. And it's Windows that does the appending.

Comment: `C:\Users\sarc83518.jdks\jdk-16.0.1\bin` - Appears to be another mistake.

Comment: @Alex: (1) Verify in CMD the value of `%USERPROFILE%`.  (2) Use `regedit` to position to `Computer\HKEY_USERS`, enter first long sub-key, then sub-key `Volatile Environment`; what do you have in item `USERPROFILE`?

Comment: @harrymc - I didn't have the time to count the characters, any event the idea behind copying then replacing the text, is to remove `C:\Users\sarc83518.jdks\jdk-16.0.1=:\Users\sarc83518.jdks\openjdk-8u282-b0;` and `C:\Users\sarc83518.jdks\jdk-16.0.1\bin` since they are obviously invalid.  Of course I suspect `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` contains those two values, could easily be fixed, and the problem would be resolved.  The author of course hasn't provided the value of that variable to us.

Comment: @Ramhound: JAVA_HOME is in the wrong position in the list.

Comment: @Alex - Please provide the value of %JAVA_HOME%

Comment: There are a bunch of duplicates in there as well ...

Comment: The one after `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` is invalid

Comment: It is 1016 characters.

Comment: @Ramhound: I can't delete those invalid entries because they are added by something, they're not in the list! That's exactly the problem I'm having!

Comment: @Alex - What Java applications have you ran that might have attempted to modify the system variable?  Are you the Administrator of this machine?

Comment: @Ramhound Testcontainers.org is a framework to run for example temporary databases for application testing purposes. At some point it tries to find a docker executable in the path, by checking one by one, When it comes to the invalid entry (the one with "=:") it crashes because it's not a valid path. It should probably just log the error and continue, but it doesn't, and I cannot change it because it's a 3rd party application.

Comment: You were asked for information about `Volatile Environment` key yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here.

1. Your path variables are repeated. Copy all the path variables to a text file.

%SYSTEMROOT% is C:\Windows

Remove the entries from 3-8

2. Uninstall JAVA on your system. You can reinstall later. Now check the path variables, and if JAVA is still there, delete it manually. As some others have others, the JAVA path variables are messed up.

Comment: 1 - Yes, there were some duplicates that I removed, but that's not going to help (and it didn't) with this problem.  
2 - There is nothing to uninstall, because I didn't install Java in the first place, I just copied the the zip file to its current location and added the correct JAVA_HOME manually. Java works fine, that's not the problem.

Comment: @Alex - You had to have installed Java since you had multiple different versions.  You installed Java or something you installed required it so it was installed. Java isn’t installed on Windows unless a user installs it.

Comment: @Alex - Just so I am a better understanding, your saying if you modify the PATH variable, then echo PATH your changes are not reflected after closing the prompt and reopening?

Comment: When I say I haven't installed, I meant I didn't run an exe or msi installer for Java. You can also download a zip file with the binaries and extract that somewhere in you disk and as long as is in the path, it'll work. That's what I did.

Comment: @Ramhound If I modify the path using the interface, changes are reflected after I restart the terminal, but that's not the problem. The problem is that invalid entry with the =: in the middle, which is not in the UI, I didn't add it, and therefore I cannot remove it. 
I could remove it by manipulating the PATH variable directly in the command line, but then the changes would be lost after a console restart.

Comment: You can permanently modify the PATH variable using a command.  That’s how most installers modify the PATH variable

Comment: And what would that command be?